# JQuery on change event does not trigger when used iteratively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I have a large set of select boxes dynamically generated and when some value is changed in any of these select boxes, some X action is performed. However the .on change function does not work as it is supposed to. Here is a snippet of my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$("body").on( 'change',$("#pipeline_stages2"),select_pipeline_stage );
  for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log("Calling the select_pipeline_stage function");
    $("body").on('change',"#pipeline_stages" + String(i) ,select_pipeline_stage(i));
  };
});
```

The commented code works but not when iterated.

Here is a snippet of the function being called.

```js
function select_pipeline_stage(i){
  var data = $('#' + $('#pipeline_stages' +String(i)+" "+ 'option:selected').val()).html();
  console.log($('#pipeline_stages' + String(i) + " " + 'option:selected').val());
  console.log("Transferred the html from the corresponding div");
  $('#stage'+String(i) +'_pipeline').html(data);
}
```

Comment: why dont you use .each function to iterate ?

Comment: Why don't you use `class` instead of `id`?

Comment: can you copy all the code in a jsfidlle please

Comment: I tried the .each function just now and it doesn't seem to work. Would using the class help? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: I tried it and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot !

Comment: I'm glad to hear :) Please accept the answer so it will help to other people..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me purpose a quite different approach.

1. Add `class` to each `select` (Let's say `pipeline_stages`).
2. Add `data-` attribute with the relevant index (Let's say `stage`).
3. Listen to all of the selects using a single selector `.pipeline_stages`.
4. Get the index by the `data-stage` attribute and the `html` by `find` function.
5. Use it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on('change',".pipeline_stages", function() {
    var elm = $(this),
        i = elm.attr('data-stage'),
        data = elm.find('option:selected').html();

    select_pipeline_stage(i, data);
  });
});

function select_pipeline_stage(i, data) {
  $('#stage' + i + '_pipeline').html(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="#pipeline_stages1" class="pipeline_stages" data-stage="1">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<select id="#pipeline_stages2" class="pipeline_stages" data-stage="2">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<select id="#pipeline_stages3" class="pipeline_stages" data-stage="3">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<hr />
<div id="stage1_pipeline"></div>
<div id="stage2_pipeline"></div>
<div id="stage3_pipeline"></div>
```